# ARM Cortex M3 - Add a new interrupt to the end of the vector table?

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller, bare-metal

I am doing some bare metal C development on an ARM Cortex M3 SoC, and I wanted to check and see if it is possible to add a new user-defined interrupt handler to the NVIC. I am adding my own IRQ with the plan of triggering it via software, either via NVIC_SetPendingIRQ() or via the NVIC->STIR register. Neither seem to work.

I have added my interrupt vector name to the end of the vector list in the CMSIS startup assembler file, and added the corresponding enum to the system header, and while debugging and executing the function call NVIC_EnableIRQ(), it doesn't correctly update the NVIC->ISER (Interrupt Set Enable Register). So I guess, the question is, can you even add your own interrupt? There are 256 total interrupts than can be used in the ARM Cortex M3, and I just followed how the others were added so I figured it wouldn't be an issue.

Thank you.

Comment: if you want to add another interrupt number then you need to be a chip vendor with the IP from arm and add logic to their core to provide that.  If you are asking about library calls then I assume you are not in a position to modify the logic in a chip?

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet for your SoC should say how many interrupts are supported by the NVIC.  While 240 is the maximum possible number for a Cortex-M3 device in general, the actual number on your chip is defined by the implementation and it makes sense to have that number be as small as possible to reduce costs.

In general, there is no way to add interrupts in software, but you might be able to use the SVCall interrupt, which is designed to be triggered by software.  Or you could find some other interrupt you aren't using in your system, and which is not being activated by hardware, and try to use that for your purposes.

References:

1. [Nested Vectored Interrupt Controller in the Cortex-M3 Devices Generic User Guide](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0552/a/cortex-m3-peripherals/nested-vectored-interrupt-controller)

Answer (score 1):

The SVC instruction invokes the `SVCall` handler with an 8-bit *service number* available to the handler which can be used to invoke a handler from a look-up table (essentially a secondary vector table for software interrupts).

An example of that can be found at https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka004005/latest, except there it uses a switch rather than a look-up table - to the same effect.

Comment: Thanks I’ll try out the SVC call. Keep in mind I’m working on this just bare metal, no OS using the GNU gcc tool chain. So I figured I was already in privileged mode. Is that not necessarily true?

Comment: @us3rnotfound :  It is not just a matter of privileged mode, SVC runs in the interrupt context.  As an interrupt handler the preemption of the SVC is determined by the NVIC priority configuration.  Otherwise you may as well invoke a regular function call via a lookup table of function pointers.